# Problems with Mi browser

Tags: javascript, xiaomi

My website has a lot of JavaScript code that doesn't seem to work on Mi browser (Xiaomi), but on other browsers everything is ok. (I work with models and es6 elements)

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: I log in and the site resets

Comment: Unfortunately, the sites that list compatibility issues (e.g. caniuse.com) don't include the Mi browser. Unless they provide resources of their own, you're going to have to test to see what features they support.

Comment: isn't there something to make it compatible?

Comment: There is no magic "make this website compatible with Xiaomi Mi browser" switch built into a general purpose programming language like JavaScript. Without any code to research compatibility, and, as @Barmar notes, little compatibility data, it is down to whether an individual has experience with this specific browser.